# App crashes if PaywithCard is selected in PayPalPaymentViewController [Paypal iOS SDK]

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I have integrated paypal's payment gate way in my app and I have added all the neccessary sdks and libraries. When I enable **acceptCreditCards** option in paypal configuration, app crashes as soon as user tries to tap on PaywithCard option.

Crash Log:

```
'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <PayPalPaymentViewController: 0x7fce3029f200
Environment: sandbox
languageOrLocale: en-US
>
```

I even tried enabling PaywithCard in paypal's sample app and observed the same behaviour.I'm using Xcode 8, swift 3 and

Answer (score 0):

I have added card.io SDK and cleaned the app before running.Now app works as expected.